# Using ANSI Codes in a C program

Tags: c

I make the follow screensaver-program. I using ANSI codes, for clear the screen of terminal and define the position of current time. However, many times printed the same ANSI codes. For example in line:

```
printf( "\e[%d;%df%s\n", random_line, random_column, ctime( &t1 ));
```

printed -->

> [0;-14fMon Jun  1 13:39:49 2015

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main( void )
{
    int lines = 0, columns = 0, random_line = 0, random_column = 0;
    time_t t1;
    struct winsize w;

    while( 1 )
    {
        printf( "\e[2J\n" );

        ioctl( 0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w );
        //printf( "Lines of Term: %d\n", w.ws_row );
        //printf( "Columns of Term: %d\n", w.ws_col );
        lines = w.ws_row;
        columns = w.ws_col;

        srand( time( NULL ) );
        random_line = rand() % lines;
        //printf( "Random Line = %d\n", random_line );
        random_column = ( rand() % columns ) - 20;
        //printf( "Random Column = %d\n", random_column );

        t1 = time( NULL );
        printf( "\e[%d;%df%s\n", random_line, random_column, ctime( &t1 ) );
        sleep( 5 );
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Be warned that `'\e'` is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Character-Escapes.html#Character-Escapes).

Comment: Also, check the return value from `ioctl( 0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w );`  In an arbitrary process, `stdout` may not support that particular `ioctl()`.

Comment: user3121023, i tried this, but nothing...

Comment: user3121023, I think that is the problem, the random_column must be positive.

Comment: I don't think the question is particularly clear.  This code compiles for me, the screen is cleared and the date/time is displayed on the rhs of the terminal

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI escape sequence is not well formed when you provide a *negative* value for either row or column, which is why you're seeing something like:

```
[0;-14fMon Jun 1 13:39:49 2015
```

rather than the string:

```
Mon Jun 1 13:39:49 2015
```

positioned somewhere.

Basically, the ANSI sequence interpreter has no idea how to place the cursor fourteen character to the left of the leftmost side of your screen, so you should probably revisit *why* you're subtracting `20` from the random value to get the column.

If it's to ensure the text fits on the line chosen without wrapping to the next line, you should instead use (changing the value as well since there's more than 20 characters in your date string):

```
random_column = rand() % (columns - 25);
```